# swift Cannot assign value of type 'Int' to type 'String'

Tags: swift, casting

Here is my code. I am a beginner using Swift and my code does not work.

Error in view controller was shown:

> Cannot assign value of type 'Int' to type 'String'

And:

> Could not cast value of type '__NSCFNumber' (0x104061840) to 'NSString' (0x1031324a8).
>   2019-09-30 01:46:05.056249+0900 Community[20037:815002] Could not cast value of type '__NSCFNumber' (0x104061840) to 'NSString' (0x1031324a8).

```
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {

    // getting index of the cell wherein comments button has been pressed
    let indexPathRow = (sender as! UIButton).tag

    // accessing segue we need -> CommentsVC
    if segue.identifier == "CommentsVC" {

        // accessing destination ViewController -> CommentsVC
        let vc = segue.destination as! CommentsVC

        // assigning values to the vars of CommentsVC
        vc.avaImage = avaImageView.image!
        vc.fullnameString = fullnameLable.text!
        vc.dateString = posts[indexPathRow]!["date_created"] as! String

        vc.textString = posts[indexPathRow]!["text"] as! String


        ////////////
        // sending id of the post
        vc.post_id = posts[indexPathRow]!["id"] as! Int


        // sending the image to the CommentsVC
        let indexPath = IndexPath(item: indexPathRow, section: 0)

        guard let cell = tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath) as? PicCell else {
            return
        }

        vc.pictureImage = cell.pictureImageView.image!

    }
```

> Cannot assign value of type 'Int' to type 'String'

on:

```
vc.post_id = posts[indexPathRow]!["id"] as! Int
```

Comment: Not directly related to your issue but you should redo your data structure to use a Swift struct instead of dictionary.

Comment: what's posts type?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please **read** the error message, it's pretty clear: `post_id` is declared as `String` but the dictionary value is an `Int`

And please conform to the Swift naming convention and name variables *lowerCamelCased*

Two solutions:

1. Declare `postId` as `Int`

   ```
   var postId : Int
   ```
2. Create a `String` from the dictionary value

   ```
   vc.postId = String(posts[indexPathRow]!["id"] as! Int)
   ```

And please conform to the Swift